# How to add +1 to the label every time sprite is touched?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, label, uilabel

I am developing a game using cocos2d 3.0.
I have a sprite. I'd like add +1 into the label every time sprite is touched( score).

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];

  if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint)) { 
 label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"1" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:23.0f];
 label.position = ccp(_contentSize.width - _contentSize.width/20,_contentSize.height - _contentSize.height/20);

 [self addChild:label ];
 }}
```

EDITED according to answers :

In `@implementation`:

```
long score;
CCLabelTTF *label;
```

In `- (id)init`:

```
    label= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:23.0f];
    label.position = ccp(_contentSize.width - _contentSize.width/20,_contentSize.height - _contentSize.height/20);

    [self addChild:label ];
```

And finally :

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];

  if (CGRectContainsPoint([_abce boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint))
{
    score++;
    [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",score ] ];

            }
```

That all doesn't work. There is just no label there.

EDITED(2):
I figured out, how to do it right. Everything is OK, except

```
 label= [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"" fontName:@"Verdana-Bold" fontSize:23.0f];
        label.position = ccp(_contentSize.width - _contentSize.width/20,_contentSize.height - _contentSize.height/20);

        [self addChild:label ];
```

It should not be placed in the init method! I placed it in onEnter method. Works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are adding a new label on every touch on the sprite. Code part as Alok Rao said. Add a CCLabelTTF *label variable (may be in init() or so) like how you did for _sprite. And take class variable int counter. Then

```
-(void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

   CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
   CGPoint convertedlocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: location];
   CGPoint convertedNodeSpacePoint = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedlocation];

   if (CGRectContainsPoint([_sprite boundingBox],convertedNodeSpacePoint)) {
      counter++; 
      [label setString:[@(counter) stringValue]; // or you can do [label setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",counter]];
```

}}

Comment: How to customize font and size in [label setString:[@(counter) stringValue]; ?

Comment: label.fontName = @"Arial"; and label.fontSize = 12.0, label.color = CCRed; like this you can change the properties of CCLabelTTF. See the CCLabelTTF.h file for more information or you can type label. then it will show you all the available attributes.

Comment: Also, I have some different sprites. When one sprite is touched twice , number 2 appears just over number 1, and if one more time - number three appears over number two. If first sprite is touched only once and then another one sprite is touched, number 2 changes number 1, doesn't cover it

Comment: Are you adding a new label each time a ccsprite is touched? See the if() condition in the touchBegan() method. You just need to set (update) the text of the label. Dont add it again. And about your second point "number 2 changes number 1" -> where is the counter variable you have declared? is it inside the touchBegan()?

Comment: There should not be a another CCLabelTTF *label in the init() apart from the class level. Try with this method once "(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(id)event" instead of touchBegan. I just tested and everything working fine in cocos2d v2.1

Comment: Xcode defines your way wrong . I am using 3.0, so I don't think that is a king of issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Keep One Counter variable (ex. iCount)
2. Create Label at the beginning (Like how you created Sprite). Make it class variable.
3. Increment counter(iCount) and use that to create string and use that in Label

Answer (score 0):

### Proper Object Oriented solution

1. Define a custom class `ScoreSprite` that can handles touch events
2. Implement the `delegation` pattern in order for the `Scene` to get notified about the `ScoreSprite` touch events
3. Use a `property` for your `score so whenever it changes, your scoreLabel does as well

Here is a sample implementation:

### UTScoreSprite.h

```
#import "CCSprite.h"

@protocol UTScoreSpriteDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) didPressSprite;

@end

@interface UTScoreSprite : CCSprite

@property (weak, nonatomic) id<UTScoreSpriteDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

### UTScoreSprite.m

```
#import "UTScoreSprite.h"

@implementation UTScoreSprite

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}

- (void) touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.delegate didPressSprite];
}

@end
```

### MainScene.h

```
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "UTScoreSprite.h"

@interface MainScene : CCNode <UTScoreSpriteDelegate>

@end
```

### MainScene.m

```
#import "MainScene.h"

@interface MainScene()

@property (weak, nonatomic) CCLabelTTF *scoreLabel;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger score;

@end

@implementation MainScene

- (void) onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self initializeSprite];
    [self initializeLabel];
    self.score = 0;
}

- (void) initializeLabel
{
    self.scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" fontName:@"Helvetica" fontSize:15.0f];
    self.scoreLabel.position = ccp(20.0f, 20.0f);
    [self addChild:self.scoreLabel];
}

- (void) initializeSprite
{
    UTScoreSprite *oneTouchSprite = [UTScoreSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"ccbResources/ccbSliderHandle.png"];
    oneTouchSprite.delegate = self;
    oneTouchSprite.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
    oneTouchSprite.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
    [self addChild:oneTouchSprite];
}

- (void) didPressSprite
{
    self.score++;
}

- (void) setScore:(NSInteger)score
{
    _score = score;
    self.scoreLabel.string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_score];
}

@end
```